# How do I factorize a matrix(m x n) into two factors (m x r, r x n) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, decomposition, factorization, matrix-factorization

I want to start with a mxn matrix A and factorise it into two matrices mxr and rxn. r can be greater than the dimensions of matrix A.

nnmf allows only for `r< min(size(A))`

Is there a way I can factorise the matrix into two matrices?

Comment: you need to be more specific on what kind of factorization you want. To me, it doesn't make sense to have r greater than min(size(A)) unless you are trying to find an overcomplete sparse basis set. In that case you need more constraints on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are some factorization functions available in matlab, see here:
http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/matrix-decomposition.html

e.g. LU / qr - factorization, cholesky etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can visit [Professor Haesun Park's Academic Home Page](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hpark/nmfsoftware.php) and download [this package](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~hpark/software/nmf_bpas.zip) from there.

Actually she implements **Non-Negative Matrix Factorization** with Alternating Non-Negativity-constrained Least Squares and Block Principal Pivoting / Active Set Methods in Matlab.

Also you can find implementation of **Mixed Membership Matrix Factorization (M3F)** in Matlab, [here](http://code.google.com/p/m3f/).